# Python combination and permuation code

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I have following code to generate the set of combination, append the combination in the list, and return list.

```
def make_combination():
  import itertools  
  max_range = 5 
  indexes = combinations_plus = []
  for i in range(0, max_range): 
    indexes.append(i)
    for i in xrange(2, max_range): 
      each_combination = [list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(indexes, i)]
      combinations_plus.append(each_combination)
  retrun combinations_plus
```

It generates so many combinations that I don't want (hard to display). But, I want the following combination:

1) [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]

2) [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 1, 4], [0, 2, 3], [0, 2, 4], [0, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]

3) [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 4], [0, 1, 3, 4], [0, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]

I think problem in the following line but I don't know what it is. Any idea about what the mistake is.

```
combinations_plus.append(each_combination)
```

Comment: What are the combinations it generates that you don't want?  And how are you determining which ones you do want?

Comment: Try using a debugger. It will help you to spot your own mistakes.

Comment: It generates all the combination once I append each combination using following code combinations_plus.append(each_combination). I don't want all combinations. I want the combinations C(N,2), C(N,3), C(N,4), and C(N,5) respectively. I want each combination put in the list.

Comment: `indexes = combinations_plus = []` - this doesn't do what you think it does. `indexes` and `combinations_plus` are **the same list**. Not two empty lists. **One** empty list with two names. Anything done to `indexes` happens to `combinations_plus`, because they're the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way of doing what you want is the following:

```
list(list(itertools.combinations(list(range(5)), i)) for i in range(2, 5))
```

Comment: Doesn't this look shorter? `[list(itertools.combinations(range(5), i)) for i in range(2, 5)]`

Answer (score 0):

To fix your original code, there were two problems:

```
indexes = combinations_plus = []
```

The above creates two names for the *exact same list*.  Appending to either appends to both which is not what you want.

The two `for` statements shouldn't be nested, or the list of indexes is incomplete:

```
for i in range(0, max_range): 
    indexes.append(i)
for i in xrange(2, max_range): 
    each_combination = [list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(indexes, i)]
    combinations_plus.append(each_combination)
```

In fact, initialize `indexes` with `range` and skip the first `for` loop:

```
indexes = range(max_range) # becomes [0,1,2,3,4]
combinations_plus = []
```

With these fixes (and fixing the spelling of `return`, you have:

```
def make_combination():
  import itertools  
  max_range = 5 
  indexes = range(max_range)
  combinations_plus = []
  for i in xrange(2, max_range): 
    each_combination = [list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(indexes, i)]
    combinations_plus.append(each_combination)
  return combinations_plus
```

Which returns (newlines added for readability):

```
[[[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]],
 [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 1, 4], [0, 2, 3], [0, 2, 4], [0, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]],
 [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 4], [0, 1, 3, 4], [0, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mark Tolonen. There is no option to make both answers correct. I also want click this as correct.